# library that invokes dialog box with pushbutton using GTK+ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gtk

Hi I am using GTK+ for the first time. Here i am trying to create GUI environment using GTK+. Here my question is - Is there any possibility to create window/dialogs, pushbuttons using GTK+ with out main function in library..?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain why you want a *static* library and define what do you mean by a "GUI environment"

Comment: I don't see why linking this thing to a shared object requires a static library. It is the opposite: it is much simpler to link a shared object to a dynamic library `libgtk-3.so` than to a static one

Comment: I still don't understand what is a "GUI environment" for you. For me it is a desktop like GNOME or some IDE like `emacs` or `geany`

Comment: It is possible to link a static library to shared object by following some rules right...! And our requirement is like that.....

Comment: No, you cannot *transparently* link a static library to some outside shared object. This is only possible for *shared* libraries

Comment: GUI Environment is like to create a window/dialog box with a text label and push buttons...

Comment: Just call that a library

Comment: ok Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically speaking, there is no such possiblity and you should not try that.

Recall that GTK is a [LGPL2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.en.html) licensed library, and that license sort-of "requires" the user to be able to upgrade the GTK library quite easily (in any proprietary application using it). The very usual way of doing that is to dynamically link the `libgtk-3.so`; as soon as that shared library is upgraded, the application using it would be able to transparently use the new version of `libgtk` ...

So make your own library a *dynamically linked ELF shared object*, as everyone do.

If you give or distribute a statically linked library using GTK, you need (to obey to the LGPL license) to provide a mean for the user to relink it to a newer version of GTK.

And your library (whatever form it has) should provide a function initializing the GTK interface, e.g. creating all the GTK widgets and installing callbacks -using `g_signal_connect` etc...- on them.

So just **make a *shared* library** e.g. `libmycode.so` (which you could link to `libgtk-3.so`) which would have some initialization functions, e.g. run the following commands (probably thru your `Makefile`) on your source files `mysrc1.c` `mysrc2.c`

```
 gcc -Wall -fPIC -O -g -c $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-x11-3.0) \
     mysrc1.c -o mysrc1.pic.o
 gcc -Wall -fPIC -O -g -c $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-x11-3.0) \
     mysrc2.c -o mysrc2.pic.o
 gcc -O -g -shared mysrc1.pic.o mysrc2.pic.o \
      $(pkg-config --libs  gtk+-x11-3.0) \
     -o libmycode.so
```

For details, read the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) & Drepper's paper: [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Notice that a static library `libsomecode.a` is just an amalgamation of member object files (`*.o`). So there is no way to transparently link it to any shared object (you could adopt an outside convention that the user of `libsomecode.a` should link a shared object `-lgtk`). In contrast, you can link a shared library `libmycode.so` to another one when building `libmycode.so`

Comment: Created [dialog box using gtk+](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-gnome/docs/gtk/html/GtkDialog.html)

Comment: then called application from library using [IPC mechanism-pipes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html)